# If $\lim_{t\to +\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{xt} \, dx=0$ then $f=0$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

> **Question,** Let $f \in L^2(0, \pi)$ such that $\lim_{t\to +\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{xt} \, dx=0$. Is it necessary that $f$ is identically zero almost everywhere?

If true, how to use the fact $\lim_{t\to +\infty} e^{xt} = +\infty, \hspace{0.5em} \forall x>0$ ?

If $f$ is positive, we can use that $\forall x>0, \hspace{0.5em} e^{tx}\geq t$ for large $t$ and we deduce

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{xt} \, dx
\geq t\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx
\to +\infty$$

if $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx  \neq 0$. But we know $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx = 0 \iff f = 0 \hspace{0.5em} \text{a.e.} $

Comment: Nice question.  I think any counterexample would have to wildly oscillate as $x \to \pi$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I’m not sure what your message is: are you saying you’ve solved it, and giving the OP hints, or are you saying that you think you’re very close with those ideas?

Comment: @FShrike I am not sure if it leads to a solution.

Comment: Many years ago, I asked a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807498/a-hard-problem-on-exponential-integration). You can probably adapt the proof from there - but I doubt a simple, real-analytic proof exists.

Comment: @dezdichado
 I think, I see now how to apply Phragmen-Lindelof theorem to my problem, I don't know if the right to give an answer by me

Comment: Maybe you can accept Pavel's answer with some edit added. Or just write a thorough answer yourself.

Comment: I will accept the Pavel's answer  and give a very detailed answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that $f$ is necessarily zero.

Assume the converse and let $\operatorname{ess\,supp}f = [a,b]\subset[-\pi, \pi]$. Then the Fourier transform $F(z) = \int_a^b f(x) e^{izx}\,dx$ of $f$ is a entire function from the Paley-Wiener space of entire functions. Moreover, exponential type of $F$ equals $\max(|a|, |b|)$.

We have $F(it) = \int_a^b f(x)e^{-tx}\,dx$. Since $f\in L^2$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to+\infty}F(it) = 0$. On the other hand, because of our assumption we also have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to-\infty}F(it) = 0$. Exponential type of $F$ can be calculated by
$$
\text{type}(F) = \limsup_{y\to+\infty}\frac{\log\max(|F(iy)|, |F(-iy)|)}{y},
$$
which is non-positive for our $F$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not able to find a reference for this formula at the moment, but it shoud follow from lecture 16 in the Levin's book "Lectures on Entire Functions".

Comment: What is ‘exponential type’?

Comment: Well, it is rate of the exponential growth of the function. Namely, $f$ is said to have exponential type $A$ if there exists $M > 0$ such that $\displaystyle |f(z)|\le M e^{A|z|}$.

Comment: @Pavel Gubkin Thanks for your proof it takes a while to understand your arguments.

Comment: I believe this is the way to go. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807498/a-hard-problem-on-exponential-integration) question,  Alexandre Eremenko gave a nice resolution using Phragmen-Lindelof, which I think can be modified for this one.

Comment: @Pavel Gubkin in your definition is that A can be zero?, i.e. can we consider that a constant function is of type 0

Comment: Yes, we can. In fact the definition should be a little more accurate: $f$ is said to have exponential type $A$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists M>0 such that |f(z)|≤Me^{(A + \varepsilon)|z|}. The class of functions of exponential type $0$ is quite wide

Comment: @ 
Pavel Gubkin
 If we accept Type 0, and as you say there are not only constant functions; it takes a little more at the end of your reasoning to arrive at a contradiction

Comment: There are not only constant functions, but they are all are not from Paley-Wiener space, i.e. they can't be represented as a Fourier transform of a function with compact support.

Answer (score 4):

**Remark**

Who knows the theorems about the rate that a Laplace transform goes to $0$?  Is that relevant?

In this problem, write $g(x) = f(\pi-x)$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $g(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Then change variable $y=\pi - x$:
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x)e^{tx}\;dx = e^{t\pi}\int_0^\infty g(y) e^{-ty}\;dy
=e^{t\pi}\mathcal L\{g\}(t)
$$
where $\mathcal L\{g\}$ is the Laplace transform of $g$.

Now there are theorems (I don't remember them offhand) relating (a) how fast $\mathcal L\{g\}(t)$ goes to $0$ as $t \to +\infty$ to (b) regularity properties of $g$.  In our case, we have $\mathcal L\{g\}(t)$ goes to zero exponentially fast: faster than $e^{-t\pi}$.  What does that say about $g$ [and therefore about $f$] ?

Comment: Now, i understand why . I like the proof of @GEdgar , it is simple and does not use complex analysis. can I add explanations in the proof ?

Comment: @Jane , Please feel free to add to this if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$EDIT 2: There is one final issue with this post that needs to be resolved. My estimate $J(t)\ge Ce^{-T\eta}e^{t\eta}$ is very intuitive, and matches all experiments, but I do not yet know how to rigorously demonstrate it.

A partial response. EDIT: Now complete, thanks to a comment from the OP.

Suppose $f\neq0\in L^2(0,\pi)$, that is, $\|f\|>0$. By Holder's inequality, for any $0<\eta<\pi$ and any $t>0$ we know: $$\left|\int_0^\eta f(x)e^{xt}\d x\right|\le\|f\|\cdot\frac{1}{2t}\sqrt{e^{2t\eta}-1}$$Fix $\eta$ such that $f$ is not identically zero Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitary. We know there is $T>0$, such that $t\ge T$ implies: $$0\le\left|\underset{I(t)}{\underbrace{\left|\int_0^\eta f(x)e^{xt}\d x\right|}}-\underset{J(t)}{\underbrace{\left|\int_\eta^\pi f(x)e^{xt}\d x\right|}}\right|\le\left|\int_0^\pi f(x)e^{xt}\d x\right|<\varepsilon$$Let $C:=\int_\eta^\pi f(x)e^{xT}\d x$. For $t>T$ I know $J(t)\ge Ce^{-T\eta}e^{t\eta}=:Ke^{t\eta}$. Suppose $\eta$ can be chosen so that $J(t)\neq0$ for all large $t$. Then we know: $$\frac{I(t)}{J(t)}\to1$$As $J(t)\to\infty$. But: $$0\le\frac{I(t)}{J(t)}\le\frac{\|f\|}{2K}\frac{\sqrt{e^{2t\eta}-1}}{t\cdot e^{t\eta}}\to0$$Which is a contradiction. So it must be that $J(t)$ is eventually zero for any choice of $\eta$ (if it is nonzero just once, at $t_0$, then the bound $J(t)\ge Ke^{-t\eta}$ shows it is nonzero for all $t>t_0$, leading to a contradiction). That is, $\int_\eta^\pi f(x)e^{xt}\d x=0$ for all large $t$.

EDIT: Thanks to the OP, we have a way to finish off my argument.

Fix $0<\eta<\pi$: $\hat f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ be the function $t\mapsto\int_\eta^\pi f(x)e^{xt}\d x$. This function is complex-analytic. Then $\hat f(t)\equiv0$ for all large $t\in\Bbb R$ means, by the identity principle, $\hat f\equiv0$ for all $t\in\Bbb C$. That is true for any $\eta$, so we may take it as true for $\eta=0$. In particular this implies all of $f$'s Fourier coefficients are zero. By the Parseval identity, $\|f\|_2=0$, so $f=0$ almost everywhere, as desired.

Old continuation/conjecture (if any reader can see how to finish off that line of argument, I'd really appreciate a comment!):

> Let $A\sqcup B$ be the nonnegative/negative Hahn decomposition for $f$. We then know: $$\int_A|f(x)|e^{xt}\d x=\int_B|f(x)|e^{xt}\d x$$For all large $t$, and neither side is zero.
>
> Since these sets are disjoint, I conjecture this is impossible. For some majority of $x$ values in, say, $B$, will be larger than those in $A$, and increasing $t$ will compound this difference so that it is impossible for the integrals to remain equal. If $A,B$ were intervals then this would be very easy to show, for instance. While I know we can approximate $A,B$ closely in measure by unions of intervals, I can't see a way to make that work at the moment. I instinctively feel that the above equality can hold for at most one value of $t$, if $|f|$ is not almost everywhere zero.

Comment: Thank you for your partial proof, it is rich, I will study it

Comment: @Jane: I believe you're writing your comment under the wrong reply.  Pavel Gubkin's answer is above this one.

Comment: @MSIS Their message is an old one. Maybe they had a now-deleted conversation in the comments?

Comment: @FShrike You have proved  that  $\int_0^\pi f(x)e^{xt} d x=0$ for large   $t$. We can use Parseval. We extend f on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by $f(-x)=f(x)$. We have  $t\to  \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{tx}\,dx $ is analytique  and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{tx}\,dx =0$ for large t, so $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{tx}\,dx =0\quad \forall t $ .  Let  $\hat f (t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-itx}\,dx $ we have  $\hat f (-it) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{tx}\,dx =0\quad \forall t,\quad $ Thus all the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are $0.$ By Parseval, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\, dx = 0.$ and f=0 ae

Comment: @Jane Thank you! I did not consider analytic continuation arguments. Your response as well as the currently most popular one both use some complex analytic ideas, interesting. I wonder if there are 'direct' real analytic proofs

Comment: @Jane I've edited in your comments to the answer

Comment: So your contradiction proves that for every $\eta,$ and for every $T>0$, there exists $t>T$ such that $J(t) = 0.$ This does not mean $J(t)$ vanishes completely for all large $t.$

Comment: @dezdichado Fixed

Comment: also, how did you obtain the lower bound for $J(t)$ ? Did you assume $f$ was positive ? Otherwise, this seems too good to be true without the details.

Comment: @dezdichado You’re right. I felt it was obvious but proving it in detail has seemed to be roughly as difficult as my $A,B$ conjecture at the bottom of the post. What I did was assume that you can just bring out the scaling, $e^{xt}=e^{xT}e^{(t-T)x}>e^{xT}e^{(t-T)\eta}$. This is highly obvious to me then that $J(t)\ge Ce^{(t-T)\eta}$, but intuition is dangerous.

Comment: @ FShrike
  so as not to mislead visitors, should I decline your answer after accepting it, I don't know the conveniences of this forum

Comment: @Jane You can unaccept, and I can add a third edit saying that some of the content of the post is still conjectural

Comment: @FShrike it happens. If you look at the link I commented, I wnet through s similar problem and ultimately concluded that  real analysis proof is almost impossible.

Comment: @dezdichado What is most striking for me is the fact that we need the exponential to be complex analytic in order to conclude the proof. However, if you give me any increasing, integrable function $g$ which blows up, I would still expect $\|f(x)g(xt)\|\to0,\,t\to\infty$ to imply $f=0$ a.e.

Answer (score 2):

I give a very detailed answer to my question, a little modified, to be more general. I had suffered to understand all the details, that's why I am giving this answer to whoever needs it

> **Question,** Let $f \in L^1(\alpha, \beta)$ , $\beta>0$ and $F(x)= \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(t)e^{xt} \, dt$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x)=0$. Is it necessary that $f$ is identically zero almost everywhere?

> First show that F is analytic on $\mathbb C$
> Let $z=a+ib$ it suffices to prove that $\frac{\partial F} {\partial b} = i\frac{\partial F} {\partial a}$. We can use to see it, differentiation under the integral sign because $\forall t\in(\alpha,\beta), \quad |tf(t)e^{t(a+ib)}|\leq M|f(t)|\in L^1(\alpha,\beta)$

> If we show that F est bounded on $\mathbb C$, then by Liouville's theorem F must be constant on $\mathbb C$ and this constant is given by $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x)=0$. Now $F(z)=0,\, \forall z\in\mathbb C$. Extend f by 0 outside $[\alpha,\beta]$,  we have  $\hat f(x)=F(-ix)=0,\, \forall x\in \mathbb R $. By injectivity of the Fourier transform on $L^1$, we conclude that $f$ is identically zero almost everywhere.

> Now, i show that that F est bounded on $\mathbb C$ by using Phragmén-Lindelöf Principle  ( I have adapted the proof drawing inspiration from  the link given by @dezdichado and answer givin by @Pavel Gubkin  )

> First i show that F is an exponential type, put $z=a+ib$
> $|F(z)|\leq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |f(t)|e^{at}\ \, dt$ . Note that
> $\forall t\in[\alpha,\beta], \quad  |t|\leq c:=max(|\alpha|,|\beta|)$ and $e^{ta}\leq e^{c|a|} \leq e^{c|z|}$  thus $|F(z)|\leq ||f||_{L^1} e^{c|z|}, \forall z\in \mathbb C$

> To conclude with Phragmén-Lindelöf Principle , it suffices to show that F is bounded on both axes.
> On the real axis: it's clear that F est bounded for x<0 and also for  $x\geq 0$ , because   F  is continuous and $F(x)\to 0$ if $x\to +\infty$ . On the imaginary axis  $|F(ix)|\leq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |f(t)e^{itx}|\ \, dt=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |f(t)|\ \, dt=||f||_{L^1}$